# Impressão por VBS - Servidor Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, servidor, vbs, vbscript

Olá!

Fiz uma rotina de impressão automática onde uma tarefa que eu criei no windows server 2008 R2 chama um script vbs , onde no mesmo é feita uma requisição HTTP por GET a um serviço web que monta um arquivo PDF em uma pasta. Daí o mesmo script após montar o arquivo, envia o mesmo para a impressora instalada como impressora padrão no servidor e o mesmo é impresso, e em seguida o arquivo enviado é apagado do servidor com a finalidade de não ocupar espaço em disco. Porém, o script só funciona quando eu o executo manualmente, ou seja, pelo agendador de tarefas do windows server 2008 R2, o script é executado ( percebi isso porque constatei que o arquivo é apagado, conforme eu mencionei acima) porém não envia o arquivo para impressão e também não retorna nenhum erro. Alguém tem alguma idéia do que seja? Segue abaixo o meu script  VBS:

```
Dim oXMLHTTP
Dim oStream

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://localhost/web/solicitacao_temporaria/imprimir", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then

TargetFolder = "C:\solicitacoes" 

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder)

Set colItems = objFolder.Items


For Each objItem in colItems
    set oWsh = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
    oWsh.run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"" /p /h C:\solicitacoes\" & objItem & ".pdf" ,,true
Next
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\solicitacoes\*.*"), DeleteReadOnly

Else
    MsgBox(oXMLHTTP.Status)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de passar por esse problema em um aplicativo desenvolvido em Delphi. O problema não tinha nada a ver com o código. Era simplesmente questão de configurar com qual programa o arquivo deve ser aberto (aquela configuração do Windows mesmo). Tenta aí e configura pra abrir com o Acrobat Reader que você tem na sua máquina. O meu estava configurado pra abrir com o navegador.

Comment: Marcelo, obrigado pela atenção, mas eu já tinha passado por esse problema, tanto é que na linha oWsh.run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"" /p /h C:\solicitacoes\" & objItem & ".pdf" ,,true  , ele configura pra abrir o Acrobat Reader que está instalado no servidor .